# How to get full AC speed on my laptop using an Intel card

Tags: wireless, hardware, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

My laptop came with a Broadcom Wi-Fi card with the M.2 socket. I got great AC speed with the card on my network, up over 800 Mb/s at times but the connections dropped randomly including wired connections.

So I purchased an Intel 7265NGW card which was recognized and works just fine. The connections are rock solid, but I am only getting N speeds which means it tops out at 300 Mb/s.

I do want to stick to Intel since it always works, but how can I get AC speed with this card, and if I can't what would I have to get to get the same performance as the Broadcom card offered. I mostly connect to Netgear Nighthawk and Ubiquity access points. I am running Ubuntu 16.10 with the 4.8.0-27-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP kernel.

Comment: Are you connected via 2.4 GHz or 5 GHz?

Comment: I am mostly connected to 5 GHz

Comment: Are you sure both antenna wires are securely connected to the card after you installed it? Max speed for single antenna on AC is around 433 Mbps.

Comment: That high even with only a N connection? The issue is that  do only get an N connection, it won't connect AC it seems.

Comment: I put the Broadcom card back in and I am again getting 800 Mb/s connections. I also tried with only one antenna connected on the Intel card and I got 150 Mb/s.

Comment: I don't know about an N connection. I have a 7265 in my laptop, and I seem to be able to get up to about 866 Mbps, but the speed keeps changing constantly in connection info. On speedtest.net I get about 300 Mbps or so over the wifi from my laptop, on a 500 Mbps upstream connection.

Comment: When I look at the connection information in network manager it always says either 300 Mb/s or it drops to 270 Mb/s when I go a bit further from the AP.   With the Broadcom it varies much more up to over 800 Mb/s. I will do some more tests with the Intel.